# lazy loading issue for attached entities

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I've changed my DAL codebase from ObjectContext (EF4) to DbContext (EF5).
My problem is when i attach an entity to DbSet and access a navigation property i got null instead of an object, however in my old code (ObjectContext case) it was returning me object and no null.

I can solve issue by explicit loading but it's a lot of pain to find all codes that uses navigation properties of attached entities.

Is there a clear solution?

Thanks

Comment: How did you created instances of entities previously and how do you create them with a new code?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka it's created by object data source in both old and my new code. i'm using data binding, object data source create entity object and pass it to my BLL.